# Relations properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $\mathrm M = \Bbb R; \mathrm R = \{(x,y)\mid x = y\}$

Investigate wheter the relation is reflexive, transitive, symemtric, antisymmetric.

- Reflexivity $\rightarrow (\forall x \in \mathrm A)[(x,x) \in \mathrm R] $
- Symetry $\rightarrow (\forall x, y \in \mathrm A)[(x,y) \in \mathrm R \implies (y,x) \in \mathrm R] $
- Antisymetry $\rightarrow (\forall x, y \in \mathrm A)[(x,y) \in \mathrm R \land (y,x) \in \mathrm R \implies x = y ]$
- Transitive $\rightarrow (\forall x, y, z \in \mathrm A)[(x,y) \in \mathrm R \land(y,z) \in \mathrm R \implies (x,z) \in \mathrm R] $

So (...)

- Reflexivity [*`TRUE`*]: $(x,y)\in \mathrm R \implies x=y \implies (x,x) \in \mathrm R$
- Symmetry[*`TRUE`*]: $(x, y)\in \mathrm R \implies x = y \implies (y, x) \in \mathrm R$
- Antisymmetry [*`TRUE`*]: $(x, y) \in \mathrm R \land (y,x) \in \mathrm R \implies x = y $
- Transitivity[*`TRUE`*]: $(x,y) \in \mathrm R \land (y,z) \in \mathrm R \implies x = y \land y = z \implies x = z \implies (x,z) \in \mathrm R$

But there's no way that a relation be Symetric and Antrisymetric.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Equality **is** both symmetric and antisymmetric: despite their names, the two properties are not contradictory. A relation cannot be both symmetric and asymmetric ($\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ implies $\langle y,x\rangle\notin R$), but as you’ve observed, a relation can be both symmetric and antisymmetric. In fact, a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is both symmetric and antisymmetric if and only if it is a subset of the equality relation on $A$; geometrically, it’s a subset of the diagonl in $A\times A$.

Comment: Then can I represent ir as a matrix?

Comment: @Tomi: Can you represent what as a matrix?